# How to connect remotely to MySQL server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, .net

What is the best way to connect remotely to `MySQL` server on domain ?

I want to make an desktop app or maybe it is easier to do it with `asp.net` ?

Comment: Show us your efforts

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Mysql Workbench for desktop use to connect to Mysql Server.
   For coding: Get Mysql client library for .net . It's called mysql connector. Add

   using Mysql.Data; namespace

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html

2. Makes no difference what kind of application you are creating.

your code will look very similar like this one:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;

myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
    "pwd=12345;database=test;";

try
{
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1- I usually use [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) tool to connect to MYSQL server otherwise on localhost or remotely servers on CPanels.

most of CPanels allow to remote connection by adding % at access hosts field to enable me connect remotely anywhere.

from your cpanel go to the database tools then -> you will find link for Remote mysql -> then you can any IP address to make server allow to connect, if you want connect anywhere you put %.

Note: CPanels are little different each others.

2- if you want connect to mysql in your code, you make a normal connection after doing step 1.